# Replace sublist in place so that the whole modified list is returned

Tags: list-manipulation

If i have a list such as:

```
data = {{{274.33`, 98.90028`}, {274.33`, 98.02906`}}, {{457.645`, 
     98.02906`}, {457.645`, 85.9109`}}, {{492.329`, 
     85.9109`}, {492.329`, 81.68262`}}, {{681.938`, 
     81.68262`}, {681.938`, 80.13062`}}, {{862.401`, 
     80.13062`}, {862.401`, 78.64416`}}, {{985.038`, 
     78.64416`}, {985.038`, 77.63547`}}, {{1087.85`, 
     77.63547`}, {1087.85`, 76.49579`}}, {{1117.983`, 
     76.49579`}, {1117.983`, 76.47131`}}};
```

I want to change every second number in the inner-most part, that is all those that are selected by a command:

```
data[[All, All, 2]]
```

I know that I can do eg.:

```
data[[All, All, 2]]=data[[All, All, 2]]+100
```

But I would like to do with a single command operating on the whole list, so that the whole changed list is returned.
I was looking at something like:

```
ReplacePart[#, {_, 2} :> 100] & /@ data[[All, 2]]
```

This works but i cannot reference the value, it just replaces that. The manual talks about using something like `{i_, i_} :> f[i]` but it does not work in this case as it only references diagonal elements in a matrix and whatever other form of that variant i do, i keep getting strange results such as:

```
{{{101, 102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 
   102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 102}, {101, 
   102}}, {{101, 102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 102}, {101, 102}}, {{101, 
   102}, {101, 102}}}
```

How do I do this problem?

Comment: `SubsetMap[# + 100 &, data, {All, All, 2}]`

Comment: `MapAt[# + 100 &, data, {All, All, 2}]`

Comment: Try:  `data /. {x1_Real, x2_} -> {x1, x2 + 100}`

Comment: `ConstantArray[{0, 100}
  , {Dimensions[data][[1]]
   , Dimensions[data][[2]]}
  ] + data`